# ¿como ingresar datos en un textbox y seguir mostrando el dato?

Tags: laravel, autocompletar, vistas

Tengo una tabla donde ingreso calificaciones de alumnos.
En cada fila o registro de la tabla tengo 3 texbox para que ingresé las calificaciones.
Necesito que al ingresarlas me las muestre allí y también poder actualizarlas allí mismo...
Ahorita envío las calificaciones y pues se quedan los campos nuevamente en blanco.
Estoy trabajando con laravel.

Espero que alguien me ayude.

Comment: Explícate un poco mas y pon código, porque no suena difícil y aun así no comprendí la mitad de lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tendras que tener una ruta para cada acción, digamos que en la ruta `create` es donde creamos nuestro alumno y la ruta `edit` donde actualizamos los datos de nuestros alumno.

```
Route::get('student/create', 'StudentController@create');
Route::get('student/update', 'StudentController@edit');
```

Ahora vamos al controlador, creamos los dos métodos para las rutas y en cada metodo devolveremos una vista diferente, pero que comparta una subvista que sera el formulario.

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('student.create');
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        return view('student.update');
    }
}
```

Ahora vamos a crear nuestras vistas. Creamos tres la vita `create` la vista `edit` y una más que llamaremos `form`.

```
// Esta seria la vista 'create', la cual tendria una formulario
// al metodo 'store' donde guardariamos nuestro usuario.

<form method="POST" action="{{ action('StudentController@store') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @include('student.form')
</form>


// Esta seria la vista 'edit', la cual tendria una formulario
// al metodo 'update' donde actualizariamos nuestro usuario.

<form method="POST" action="{{ action('StudentController@update', $student) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('put') }}
    @include('student.form')
</form>
```

Por ultimo creamos la vista `form` donde trendiamos el formulario tanto para crear como para actualizar nuestros usuarios.

```
<input name="name" value="{{ $student->name or old('name') }}" type="text">
<input name="date_birth" value="{{ $student->date_birth or old('date_birth') }}" type="date">
```

El truco esta en combiar la logica `or` con el método `old`, Ex: `{{ $student->name or old('name') }}`. Asi conseguimos que cuando exista usuario es decir cuando actualicemos nos muestre su no nombre y si no existe usuario mostrara los datos del request, que si no existe devolvera null.